# Field 'codigo_cad' expected a number but got <Customer: 1>

Tags: python, django

I have no idea how to fix this: I'm having problems when pulling the `customer.codigo_cad`, because I have the ***str*** functionality that only sends a string, and the object is requesting an int, whenever I try to move this part the error becomes bigger, like the location reads as if was a table object, and not an int, thanks in advance to anyone who helps me

My models:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.codigo_cad)

def get_aniversario(self):
    return f'{self.aniversario_cad.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") if self.aniversario_cad != None else "30/12/1899"}'

# clica na pessoa e retorna os detalhes dela
def get_customer_url(self):
    return f'/customer/{self.codigo_cad}'

# clica em vendas e retorna as vendas da pessoa
def get_sale_customer_url(self):
    return f'/venda/?customer_sale={self.codigo_cad}'
```

My views:

```
def altera_venda(request,pk):
    order_forms = Venda()
    item_order_formset = inlineformset_factory(Venda,ItemVEN,form=ItemVenForm,extra=0,can_delete=False,min_num=1,validate_min=True)
    venda = get_object_or_404(Venda,pk=pk)                        # recupera venda
    #desconto = f'{venda.desconto_ven:,}'                          # formata desconto
    cliente = get_object_or_404(Customer,pk=venda.cliente_ven) # para recuperar os dados do cliente da venda
    clientes = Customer.objects.all().order_by('pk')              # para o modal clientes
    produtos = Produto.objects.all().order_by('pk')               # para o modal produtos
    itens = ItemVEN.objects.filter(num_ven_ite=pk)                # recupera itens venda
    itens_venda = []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually occurs when you pass the whole model object instead of int (just an id or pk). For example, you have a model called MyModel:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    ...
```

Then you retrieve the model instance from the database.

```
model_instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
```

You have some function that takes argument "id" that should be an integer.

```
def some_func(id: int):  # Function expects id as integer.
    ...
```

And if you pass the whole instance it will raise an exception.

```
some_func(model_instance)  # Potentially could raise an exception.
```

But if you will pass only id for example like this everything will be okay.

```
some_func(model_instance.id)
```

or

```
some_func(model_instance.pk)
```